# How to wrapper "opencore" lib to a windows phone Component?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-phone-8, opencore

on other platform like iOS Android,I find many sample about this,but for windows phone,because opencore is written by C++,How I can convert it a WRT Component? thx

Comment: Please check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh755833.aspx

Comment: so,What you mean is "map the C++/CX type to exist C++ lib,and pick some funtions that I need ..and Wrap it in my C++/Cx class"?